# Regular Expression in Javascript for number with decimal

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regular expression for a textbox which allows only 3 digits and passes following criterias:

1. Only digits (234 or 123) or
2. Only one decimal at the end (55.1)
3. Should not allow spaces
4. If decimal is used then there should be a number after/before decimal as well (555. or 12. or .12 should not be allowed)

I have following RE which works partially:

```
/^\d{0,3}$|^\d{0,2}[\.]\d{1}$/
```

Any help in modifying this ?

Looks like problem is additional:

I am using the code at keypress. So it validates each pressed value at key press.

```
  if (window.event)    {
        knum = e.keyCode;
    }
    else if (e.which)    {
        knum = e.which;
    }
    kchar = String.fromCharCode(knum);
    numcheck = /^\d{0,3}$|^\d{0,2}[\.]\d{1}$/;

    alert(numcheck.test(kchar));
```

It returns false for any decimal key press. Even if I enter 55 and then try a decimal in middle to make it 5.5, ite returns false.

Comment: Just change you {0,2} to {1,2}, but everything else seems fine to me.
What doesn't work ?

Comment: just for clarity: you're checking a string that is, by definition 1 char in length: `String.fromCharCode(knum)`, why are you matching against a pattern that allows for up to 4 characters?

Comment: So that they donot enter unwanted characters into checkbox. So when I had only numbers ( /\d/ ), the code was working fine. I changed it to include decimals and realised that it is not gonna work. That is modified my question and provided code.

Comment: You need to match the kchar against /[0-9.]/ then.  You have to check overall validity after they're done typing with one of the regexes below.  Otherwise, they'll type something like 55. and you'll stop them before they can hit the last digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need at least 1 digit, but 3 at most: `\d{1,3}`

OR

There have to be at least 1 but no more than 2 digits before and 1 after the decimal: `\d{1,2}[.]\d`

So these combined: `/(^\d{1,3}$|^\d{1,2}[.]\d$)/`

**UPDATE:**

You are testing the character which was added on the keypress event, not the full value of the input field. This would never have the expected result.

```
document.getElementById("yourfield").onkeyup = function(e) {

    // the event
    if (!e) e = window.event;

    // determine the target of the keyup event (the input field)
    var targ;
    if (e.target)
       targ = e.target;
    else if (e.srcElement)
       targ = e.srcElement;
    if (targ.nodeType == 3) // defeat Safari bug
       targ = targ.parentNode;

    // get the value
    kchar = targ.value;
    numcheck = /^\d{0,3}$|^\d{0,2}[\.]\d{1}$/;

    // test
    alert(numcheck.test(kchar));
}
```

Comment: Somehow, with above code, I am not able to type anything atall after decimal.

Answer (score 1):

Try `/^\d{1,3}|(\d{1,2}\.\d)$/`?

Your character class should not escape the period, so it should be `[.]`, though I prefer to write just `\.` because it's a waste to create a class for one character.  Similarly, `\d{1}` is redundant when `\d` means exactly the same thing.   I'm also assuming that you don't want to allow an empty text box, either, so I wrote something that allows 1-3 digits, or 1-2 digits, a period, then one more digit.  If that's wrong, you can change the range on that first `\d` back to `{0,3}`, which will allow for a text box containing nothing at all.

Comment: Can I probably compare it in the code at   kchar = String.fromCharCode(knum);  step ??

Comment: I mean instead of taking single character and comparing, if i take already existing text in input box and concatenate with the string entered giving me complete text ? Any similar thing if possible ?

Comment: Compare the individual chars against `/[0-9.]/` if you like, then append them, but then do one last check at the end before submitting or processing the value to see if the overall format is correct using the full regex.  And always remember that they could turn JavaScript off and just put anything in there.

Answer (score 0):

Use this re:

```
/^\d{1,3}$|^\d{1,2}[.]\d$/
```

Comment: That violates their condition #2:  "Only one decimal at the end (55.1)"